# Trying to get my C++ code to compile, g++ not recognized?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I've read a bunch of questions and answers on here as well as different how-to's and nothing seems to be working. I've downloaded MinGW and cygnus and I followed all of the steps to a T in this article:
http://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html

But it still gives me the `'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error. I have tried to compile in VSCode and just on the command line. What's going wrong?

Comment: If you have added the path of g++.exe into the $PATH environment variable and rebooted your computer, I do not see a reason that this won't work. Are you sure you have added the correct path?

Comment: You need to look up how to add g++ to path in Windows. The terminal does not know what g++ is until you add it to the path.

Comment: I added this path: `C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin` to both the user and the system path variables and rebooted. The g++.exe is located in this folder

Comment: Since adding it have you tried to compile? @GabyJustice

Comment: yes and I get the same error :(

Comment: You added it to the environment variables right?

Comment: 1. Verify that the path `C:\sygnux\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin` _actually exists_. 2. Verify that `g++.exe` is in that folder. 3. Enter `path` at the command prompt and verify that it is listed in the (messy) output, separated from others by a semicolon.

Comment: Okay, so **1:** It exists, I am in the folder in my file explorer and **2:** g++.exe is there. **3:** the path I added for whatever reason isn't there, but `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe;` is there. @Dúthomhas

Comment: @GabyJustice are you sure it is under `Environment Variables`?

Comment: yeah, system properties> environment variables right? With then user variables and system variables?

Comment: I tried running through and adding it to the environment variables a **_Second Time_** and restarting my computer and it miraculously worked? Thanks for the help all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I don't like keeping *everything* in the system PATH. This leads to problems when you have multiple tools installed.

**The key to managing your environment is controlling the PATH.**

If you are in the directory with g++.exe, you will see the PATH as part of the command prompt:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
```

Add it to the PATH with the following command:

```
path C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
```

Now you can change directory to your project and compile normally.

(The path “C:\MinGW\bin” is what needs to be added to the system environment PATH variable.)